# ubuntu openstack ocata - Discovering versions from the identity service failed

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, openstack

command:

```
openstack --os-auth-url http://controller:5000/v3 \
--os-project-domain-name default --os-user-domain-name default \
--os-project-name demo --os-username demo token issue
```

error:

> Discovering versions from the identity service failed when creating
>   the password plugin. Attempting to determine version from URL.
>   Internal Server Error (HTTP 500)

Error coming in keystone.log:

```
 2018-06-12 10:40:05.888577 mod_wsgi (pid=16170): Target WSGI script '/usr/bin/keystone-wsgi-admin' cannot be loaded as Python module.
2018-06-12 10:40:05.888611 mod_wsgi (pid=16170): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/usr/bin/keystone-wsgi-admin'.
2018-06-12 10:40:05.888634 Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-06-12 10:40:05.888656   File "/usr/bin/keystone-wsgi-admin", line 51, in <module>
2018-06-12 10:40:05.888688     application = initialize_admin_application()
2018-06-12 10:40:05.888702   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystone/server/wsgi.py", line 129, in initialize_admin_application
2018-06-12 10:40:05.888726     config_files=_get_config_files())
2018-06-12 10:40:05.888739   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystone/server/wsgi.py", line 53, in initialize_application
2018-06-12 10:40:05.888759     common.configure(config_files=config_files)
2018-06-12 10:40:05.888772   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystone/server/common.py", line 30, in configure
2018-06-12 10:40:05.888792     keystone.conf.configure()
2018-06-12 10:40:05.888805   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystone/conf/__init__.py", line 126, in configure
2018-06-12 10:40:05.888826     help='Do not monkey-patch threading system modules.'))
2018-06-12 10:40:05.888839   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py", line 2288, in __inner
2018-06-12 10:40:05.888860     result = f(self, *args, **kwargs)
2018-06-12 10:40:05.888872   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py", line 2478, in register_cli_opt
2018-06-12 10:40:05.888892     raise ArgsAlreadyParsedError("cannot register CLI option")
2018-06-12 10:40:05.888915 ArgsAlreadyParsedError: arguments already parsed: cannot register CLI option
```

error.log:

```
[Tue Jun 12 10:12:18.510745 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 29892:tid 139804806121344] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Jun 12 10:12:29.674244 2018] [wsgi:warn] [pid 16158:tid 139690338350976] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.11.
[Tue Jun 12 10:12:29.674304 2018] [wsgi:warn] [pid 16158:tid 139690338350976] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.12.
[Tue Jun 12 10:12:29.676957 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 16158:tid 139690338350976] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jun 12 10:12:29.676985 2018] [core:notice] [pid 16158:tid 139690338350976] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Please can somebody help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Are you getting same error if you tried for another time ?

Comment: No, still facing the issue.

Comment: Getting some exception and it is seen in keystone.log. I have added exception portion of  keystone.log above. Please verify it and help if you can. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved.

Error was in mod_wsgi according to log. Web Service Gateway Interface (WSGI) middleware pipeline for the Identity service is configured in keystone-paste.ini file, thus verified my file with the openstack docs keystone-paste.ini file available on internet thus changed pipeline configuration and issue get solved.

I have edited **/etc/keystone/keystone-paste.ini** file

1. Under [pipeline:public_api]

   pipeline = healthcheck cors sizelimit http_proxy_to_wsgi osprofiler url_normalize request_id

changed above line to:

```
pipeline = healthcheck cors sizelimit http_proxy_to_wsgi osprofiler url_normalize request_id build_auth_context token_auth json_body ec2_extension public_service
```

2. Same way edited [pipeline:admin_api]

   pipeline = healthcheck cors sizelimit http_proxy_to_wsgi osprofiler url_normalize request_id

changed pipeline to:

```
pipeline = healthcheck cors sizelimit http_proxy_to_wsgi osprofiler url_normalize request_id build_auth_context token_auth json_body ec2_extension s3_extension admin_service
```

3. Also made changes in [pipeline:api_v3]

   pipeline = healthcheck cors sizelimit http_proxy_to_wsgi osprofiler url_normalize request_id

changed above line to:

```
pipeline = healthcheck cors sizelimit http_proxy_to_wsgi osprofiler url_normalize request_id build_auth_context token_auth json_body ec2_extension_v3 s3_extension service_v3
```

By making following changes issue get solved.